# android image too large to draw

Tags: android, uiimagview

I wrote this code and I don't know what problem do I have, and how to solve it.
I want to show a list of 800 title and I want to start with an imageView that I want to show for 5 seconds and then I want to go to the Main page. When I try to run I get this error: the Image is too large. I already converted the Image to a webp and now the weight is 1.9Mb. I don't know why the image is too large?

```
public class activity_intro extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_intro);

        ImageView img_intro = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_intro); // Create an icon
        Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.img_intro).into(img_intro);

        new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                final Intent intro_toMain = new Intent(activity_intro.this, Activity_Main.class);
                startActivity(intro_toMain);
            }
        }.start();
    }

}
```

This is the LogCat

```
06-29 14:00:17.710 28527-28527/com.huawei.b_happy.cantipopolari W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(113246208bytes) bitmap.
06-29 14:00:17.711 28527-28527/com.huawei.b_happy.cantipopolari W/System.err:     at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
        at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1415)
        at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:546)
        at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1301)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17256)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16221)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17022)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3777)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3560)
        at android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:1963)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16216)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17022)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3777)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3560)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16216)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17022)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3777)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3560)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16216)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17022)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3777)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3560)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16216)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17022)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3777)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3560)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16216)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17022)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3777)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3560)
        at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17259)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:801)
        at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16221)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:677)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:683)
        at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:797)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2997)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2791)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2382)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1372)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6774)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:926)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:735)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:667)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:912)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:761)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
06-29 14:00:17.712 28527-28527/com.huawei.b_happy.cantipopolari W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:942)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:832)
```

Answer (score 1):

It says the image size is too large. So resize it using -

```
Picasso.get().load(R.drawable.img_intro).resize(100, 200).centerCrop().into(img_intro);
```

where 100 specifies the width & 200 specifies the height.